# Shinydashboard - show or hide tab based on log in info AND selectinput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm working on a shinydashboard that is secured using shinymanager and I am having trouble. I want to make a tab appear or disappear based on two bits of information. I have saved in my shinymanager credentials a user code that says what their home organization is. In my app I also have a selectInput that allows the user to choose a particular user code. I have tabs that I would like to show only if the user code for that user's credentials match the selected user code from selectInput. So for example, in the below example, if I had in res_auth a field called 'unit' with the choices aa, bb, cc, dd, ee - and the user who logs in is in unit aa, and they choose aa from the selectInput, then the iris tabs would show up - but if they choose bb they would not see the iris tabs.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinymanager)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

options(warn=-1)
data(iris)
data(mtcars)

tabset1 = tabsetPanel(id = "mtcars",
                            tabPanel(id = "mtplots","mtcars plots",
                                     fluidRow(box(title = "Plot1", plotOutput("mtcarsplot1"))
                            )),
                            
                            
                            tabPanel(id = "mttable","MTcars tables",
                                     fluidRow(box(title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("mtcarstable1")))
                            ))



tabset2 = tabsetPanel(id = "iris",
                      tabPanel(id = "iris","iris plots",
                               fluidRow(box(title = "Plot1", plotOutput("irisplot1"))
                               )),
                      
                      
                      tabPanel(id = "mttable","iris tables",
                               fluidRow(box(title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("iristable1")))
                      ))




# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(

  
  dashboardHeader(),
  
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
    selectInput("which unit", "Choose a unit", choices = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd")),
    menuItem("MTCARS", tabName = "mt", icon = icon("user-tie")),
    selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars)),
    
#    RIGHT HERE
    
    menuItem("IRIS", icon = icon("envelope-open-text"), tabName = "ir"),
    
    selectInput("irvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(iris))
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("ir", tabset2),
      tabItem("mt", tabset1)
      )
      
    )
  )




ui <- secure_app(ui, enable_admin = TRUE)


# Begin Server ----------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials("mycredentials.sqlite")
  )
  
  output$mtcarsplot1=renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = input$mtvar)) + stat_bin(nbins = input$irislines)
    
    
  })
  
  output$irisplot1=renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$irvar)) + stat_bin(nbins = input$mtlines)
    
    
  })
  
  
  output$mtcarstable1=renderTable({
    head(mtcars, input$mtlines)
    
  })
 
  
  output$iristable1=renderTable({
    head(iris, input$irislines)
    
  })
  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

First replace the line below `# RIGHT HERE` with:

```
uiOutput("test"),
```

Then add a function like this to the server:

```
output$test <- renderUI({
        if(input$`which unit`=="aa") {
            menuItem("IRIS", icon = icon("envelope-open-text"), tabName = "ir")
        }
    })
```

You will need to add a condition to the `if` to require their credentials to match in your situation, but this is essentially what you want.

Comment: Will this make the tabs appear as well? I want the tabset to appear based on these credentials as well.